# Issue with private set in list properties

Tags: c#

I have this piece of code:

```
public List<IVehicle> Vehicles { get; private set; }
```

My question is even though i am using a private set, why i can still add values to this list.

Comment: return `Vehicles.AsReadOnly` in `get`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When use use a `private set` what that means is that the property itself is un-setable from outside the class, not that it's methods are not available, and `List<T>.Add()` is only a method that the compiler knows nothing about.

By example:

```
public class VehicleContainer{
   public List<IVehicle> Vehicles { get; private set; }
   ...
}
....
VehicleContainer vc = new VehicleContainer();
vc.Vehicles  = new List<IVehicle>() // this is an error, because of the private set
int x = vc.Vehicles.Count; // this is legal, property access
vc.Vehicles.Add(new Vehicle()); //this is legal, method call
```

Take a look [at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443144/resticting-access-to-method-calls-on-read-only-properties), where use of the `ReadOnlyCollection` class is explained in the case when you want to restrict access to the collection itself, as well as the reference to the collection.

Answer (score 2):

With private `Set`, you can't set the list to some new list from outside of your class. For example if you have a this list in a class:

```
class SomeClass
{
public List<IVehicle> Vehicles { get; private set; }
}
```

then while using:

```
SomeClass obj = new SomeClass();
obj.Vehicles = new List<IVehicle>(); // that will not be allowed. 
                                     // since the property is read-only
```

It doesn't prevent you assessing the `Add` method on the list. e.g.

```
obj.Vehicles.Add(new Vehicle()); // that is allowed
```

To **return a Read-Only list** you may look into [List.AsReadOnly Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78dcd75.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

`.Add()` is a function on the class `List<>` so after you `get` the list you can call the function. You can't replace the list with another one.

You could return an `IEnumerable<IVehicle>` that would make the list (sortof) readonly.

Calling `.AsReadOnly()` on the list would result in a really readonly list

```
private List<IVehicle> vehicles;

public IEnumerable<IVehicle> Vehicles 
{ 
    get { return vehicles.AsReadOnly(); }
    private set { vehicles = value; }
}
```

Comment: Well, it would *sort* of make it read-only... but callers could still cast.

Answer (score 1):

Because `private set;` will not allow you to set list directly but you still can call methods of this list as it is using getter. You may want to use next:

```
    //use this internally
    private List<IVehicle> _vehicles;

    public ReadOnlyCollection<IVehicle> Vehicles
    {
        get { return _vehicles.AsReadOnly(); }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Getters and setters works on instances; not on properties of instances. An example;

```
Vehicles = new List<IVehicle>(); //// this is not possible
```

but if there is an instance it is possible to change its properties.

Answer (score -1):

You can only instantiate it inside the containing class / struct of the `List<IVehicle>`. But once you have an instance, you can add items to it even outside, since the object is publicly visible.